# How to re-initialize an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application, the data in one model is "meta" in nature and defines the attributes in another model. Imagine retrieving a database, where the column definition data determines the attributes of each row.

I can `reopen()` the row model so long as I have not yet requested rows from the store. A subsequent call to `store.findAll('row')` retrieves data with all the attributes defined.

If however I have already called `store.findAll('row')` prior to `Column.reopen()`, then I cannot find a way cause the store to acknowledge the new attributes.

I have tried without success:

- unloading all the rows and finding them again
- calling peekAll/update on the rows already in the store
- calling `Ember.defineProperty()` on the row model instead of reopen.

Both existing and subsequent new rows do not get the new attributes.

Comment: This is not how ember data works. Its strongly typed. May use a `field` model with `name` and `value` as attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I doubt it would scale, even if I could get these to load in one transaction with a `hasMany`. Ember is already borderline too slow for my application. If there really is no answer to my question (other than "don't do that"), I think my best option is to stringify the dynamic attributes into a single string attribute and handle them outside of ember-data, or jettison ember-data altogether.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to ask my question: I can reinitialize the entire store, but would prefer to just (re-)initialize a single model.

Comment: Are you sure this won't scale? I doubt that! How many Records do you want to manage? Performance probably hardly never come from ember-data, but always from your code, the rendering layer, observers and so on...! But if you really really want that, you should dive into the `ember-data` codebase! Checkout how the store works, and implement your own `service:store` by extending `DS.Store`

Comment: 10^3.5 rows x 10^1.5 columns. I doubt it will scale given that it is already a couple of binary orders of magnitude too slow. There are also other complications because the data type is not identical for each column. You are correct in that the computed values are an issue. I have some relatively expensive operations needed to turn the back-end data into something that ember can manipulate easily. I am trying unregistering and re-registering the module, which has helped in one scenario, but not another. I'm still investigating....

Comment: So 100000 Records? That seems not so much! I mean, you probably don't need to view all of that at once, so you could load them partially! Load only what you need to view. And that the data type is not identical is not a problem. Polymorphic relationships can solve that. But still, i don't get why you need this. Your DB Model is static, why don't define your Ember Model at compile time?

Comment: Actually they are all needed in memory at once to support the data operations. "Your DB Model is static". No it isn't; that's the point. The DB model is dynamic, and may be changed by the user directly, or by other users via the cloud (couchdb/pouchdb). Hence the problem of update the schema dyanmically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that works for me is:

```
  let store = this.get('store');

  Ember.getOwner(store).unregister('model:item');
  Item.reopen(newAttributes);
  Ember.getOwner(store).register('model:item', Item);

  let currentRoute = this.get('currentRoute');
  if (currentRoute) {
    currentRoute.refresh();
  }
```

I register the route with the service that updates the schema. When the schema change is detected (which I debounce to avoid thrashing), I unregister the model, update it with reopen, re-register it and refresh the route. There may be a way to get the store to reflect these changes without refreshing the route, but I could not find it.